# mock object is not working while trying to access private method using reflection in junit

Tags: java, junit, mocking

Mock object is not working when i try to access private method using reflection

**Main Class:**

```
@Component
public class ActualClass{
@Autowired 
MockClass data;
private String sampleMethod(String data){
//
List<String> list=data.getdata("something") // trying to mock this line 
//}
}
```

**Mock Class:**

```
@Component
public class MockClass{
public List<String> getdata(String serviceName){
return restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:9000/data/something", 
ArrayList.class); this line will return some datas as list}
}
```

**My TestCase:**

```
public class TestCases{

@Autowired 
MockClass mockobj;

@Autowired
@InjectedMocks
ActualClass actualClass

@Test
public void valid(){
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

List<String> obj=new ArrayList<String>();
obj.add("something")
when(mockobj.getdata("something")).thenreturn(obj);

Class<?> cObject=Class.forName("com.ActualClass");
ActualClass actualClass=(ActualClass) cObject.newInstance();
Method method=cObject.getDeclaredMethod("sampleMethod",String.class);
method.setAccessible(true);
method.invoke(actualClass,"date");}
}
```

can you anyone tell me whats going wrong in my test cases? the same mock object is working when i access public method.

i am having problem with only private method.

how can i solve this?

Comment: Rather than trying to do those tricky things, [test your private method through the public methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1043013/545127).

Comment: i am doing code coverage so i need to cover all the methods.

Comment: You still achieve that by only testing public method. If a private method would remain untested, then the method isn't called anyway and can be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few testing smells you should avoid.

- You should test behaviour of your objects not their implementation details. Private methods are implementation details and as such are likely to change
- Tests should not use reflection. Reflection depends on implementation details of your objects which makes tests fragile
- Code coverage should not be goal of testing. When metric becomes the goal it stops being a good metric

How you should test it then?

Mock your `MockClass` and test through the public method. If writing such test is overly awkward, fragile or not possible you should reconsider your design.